# Resize table width onload of src in iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, dynamic

The following code works and I am able to raise the alert on click of the body.  What I want to do is when the iframe is loaded, automatically change the width of the table in the iframe to 100%. So instead of click, how can I change the width onload?

```
$("iframe[name=myheader]").load(function() {
            var iframe_body = window.myheader.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            $(iframe_body).click(function() {
                alert("hello, you touched me~");
                $(this).find("table").css("width","100%"); 
            });

        });
```

Comment: it is in the same domain.  If I change .click to **each** it only works if I leave the alert in place: it's like the table is not found until there is a delay, perhaps from the actual content in the iframe not fully rendered.

Comment: It's a dynamically built page that supports two applications.  In one app it should never expand to 100%, in the other (this one) it should expand to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

New

Put this code into your iframe document :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("table").css("width","100%");
});
```

OLD------------------

iframe load() function is fired only when the iframe finish loading so you can just remove the click() event and resize.

```
$("iframe[name=myheader]").load(function() {
            var iframe_body = window.myheader.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            //$(iframe_body).click(function() {
                alert("hello, you touched me~");
                $(this).find("table").css("width","100%"); 
            //});

        });
```

Comment: Moe it's a dynamically created iframe so adding $("table... in doc ready doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the onload event of the iframe. For example, if your iframe is something like this

```
    <iframe id="frameElem" width="100%" height="100%" onload="frameLoaded(); return false" />
```

Now in the javascript code,

```
    function frameLoaded(){
    $('#frameElem').contents().find('table').css("width","100%");
    }
```